# Faker, Populator in multiple languages (English & Russian)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, faker

I'm using the Ruby Gems [Faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker), [Populator](https://github.com/ryanb/populator) to create a list of fake users in my development environement.

In my database Schema I have the following table

```
admin_customers
|- latin_first_name
|- latin_middle_name
|- latin_last_name
|- cyrillic_first_name
|- cyrillic_middle_name
|- cyrillic_last_name
```

Here is an example of how I would like to store data against each field:

```
latin_first_name = "Viola"
latin_middle_name = "Lyagushkina"
latin_last_name = "Georgievna"
cyrillic_first_name = "Виола"
cyrillic_middle_name = "Люгашкина"
cyrillic_last_name = "Георгиевна"
```

This is what my populate.rake file looks like:

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Create 100 customers"
  task :populate => :environment do
      require 'populator'
      require 'faker'
      Admin::Customer.destroy_all
      Admin::Customer.populate 100 do |customer|
        Faker::Config.locale = :ru
           customer.cyrillic_first_name = Faker::Name.first_name
           customer.cyrillic_middle_name = Faker::Name.last_name
           customer.cyrillic_last_name = Faker::Name.last_name
        Faker::Config.locale = :en
           customer.latin_first_name = Faker::Name.first_name
           customer.latin_middle_name = Faker::Name.last_name
           customer.latin_last_name = Faker::Name.last_name
      end
      puts "created 100 users"
  end
end
```

However all the data is generated in Latin, do you know how to generate multiple languages with Faker and Populator to a single record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the [YML](https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/master/lib/locales/ru.yml) file gives clarity into the available commands for the given language, the syntax was correct however the commands required to generate a cyrillic name were not.

```
Faker::Config.locale = :ru
   customer.cyrillic_first_name = Faker::Name.male_first_name
   customer.cyrillic_middle_name = Faker::Name.male_middle_name
   customer.cyrillic_last_name = Faker::Name.male_last_name
```