# How to populate a DB field in multiple languages with a Factory in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create a Factory to populate a Post with dummy data.
In this Post model, the title should be translated into English and Italian.
But I can't find in the documentation how to write a Factory that addresses this task.

To manage the content translations I'm using this package: spatie/laravel-translatable

I see that in the DB the translated data are stored in a JSON format:
For example the field title is:

```
{"en":"english title","it":"titolo italiano"}
```

Is it possible to do that?

This is the code of the definition function of my factory at the moment.

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Insight;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class InsightFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Insight::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
     public function definition()
     {

        return [
            'title' => $this->faker->sentence($nbWords = 7, $variableNbWords = true),
        ];
     }
 }
```

P.S.
There is a similar question but it's for Ruby on Rails.
[Faker, Populator in multiple languages (English & Russian)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963561/faker-populator-in-multiple-languages-english-russian)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

```
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'title' => [
            'en' => $this->faker->sentence($nbWords = 7, $variableNbWords = true),
            'it' => $this->faker->sentence($nbWords = 7, $variableNbWords = true),
        ],
    ];
 }
```